# Can't understand the proof behind the use of this map<> method

Tags: c++

> Drazil is playing a math game with Varda.
>
> Let's define  for positive integer x as a product of factorials of its
>   digits. For example, f(135) = 1! * 3! * 5! = 720.
>
> First, they choose a decimal number a consisting of n digits that
>   contains at least one digit larger than 1. This number may possibly
>   start with leading zeroes. Then they should find maximum positive
>   number x satisfying following two conditions:
>
> 1. x doesn't contain neither digit 0 nor digit 1.
> 2. = f(x) = f(a)
>
> Help friends find such number.
>
> Input The first line contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 15) — the number
>   of digits in a.
>
> The second line contains n digits of a. There is at least one digit in
>   a that is larger than 1. Number a may possibly contain leading zeroes.
>
> Output Output a maximum possible integer satisfying the conditions
>   above. There should be no zeroes and ones in this number decimal
>   representation.
>
> Examples
>   input
>   4
>   1234
>   output
>   33222
>
> input
>   3
>   555
>   output
>   555

Here is the solution,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  map<char, string> mp;

  mp['0'] = mp['1'] = "";
  mp['2'] = "2";
  mp['3'] = "3";
  mp['4'] = "223";
  mp['5'] = "5";
  mp['6'] = "35";
  mp['7'] = "7";
  mp['8'] = "2227";
  mp['9'] = "2337";

  int n;
  string str;

  cin>>n>>str;

  string res;

  for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    res += mp[str[i]];

  sort(res.rbegin(), res.rend());

  cout<<res;

  return 0;
}
```

I'd like if someone explains the reason why were the digits transformed into other form of digits rather than just with some way to compute the number with..sadly brute force would give a TLE(Time limit exceeded) in this question cause of the 15 digit thing so that's a big number to brute force to,so I kindly hope that someone can explain the "proof" below, cause idk what theory says that these numbers can be transformed to those numbers for example 4 to 223 and stuff.
Thanks in advance.

[Picture: What the proof says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycdR9.png)

Comment: I think there are missing bits in the explanation. _"Let's define for positive integer x as a product of factorials of its digits. For example, ."_, can't really understand this sentence, looks like the example is missing. Later, _"2. = f(x) = f(a)"_, what is _f_? It also seems there is something missing before the first equals sign.

Comment: Sorry I edited it @jdehesa seems like the quote eliminated this part of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory behind these transformations is the following (Ill use 4 as an example):

```
4! = 3! * 2! * 2!
```

A longer sequence of digits will always produce a larger number than a shorter sequence (at least for positive integers). Thus this code produces a longer sequence where possible. With the above example we get:

```
4! = 3! * 4
```

We can't reduce the 3! any further, since 3 is a prime. 4 on the other hand is simply 2²:

```
4 = 2² = 2! * 2!
```

Thus we have found the optimal replacement for 4 in the number-sequence as "322". This can be done for all numbers, but prime-numbers aren't factorisable and will thus always be the best replacement available for them self.

And thanks to the fact that we're using prime factorization we also know that we have the only (and longest possible) string of digits that can replace a certain digit.

Comment: I can't seem to understand this part: 
4! = 3! * 2! * 2!
From where did we get this conclusion that 4! is 3! * 2! * 2! and that for example 6! is 5! * 3!

Comment: `4! = 4 * 3 * 2 = 2 * 2 * 3 * 2 = 2! * 2! * 3!` (order doesn't matter since we'll sort afterwards anyways) thats a simple mathematical fact. Due to the definition of `f(x)`, we can do this with every digit without altering the result of `f(x)`. Those were precalculated.

Comment: I kind of understood it so @jdehesa 6! = 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 which means 6! = 3 * 2 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 and that means 6! = 3! * 5! which is translating to 35.

Comment: @Kalcor I agree that 6! = 3 * 2 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2, but then shouldn't it be 6! = 2! * 3! * 5!, which would in turn translate to 235 and not just 35? Or I'm just missing something.

Comment: @jdehesa you could easily test that with a calculator, but anyways you have to take into account `2! * 3! * 5! = 2 * 3 * 2 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2`, on the other hand `6! = 6 * 5  * 4 * 3 * 2 = 3 * 2 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2`. The `2!` would introduce another 2 into the calculation, leading to incorrect results.

Comment: @Paul I really don't think so. Test it with the calculator, 6! = 720,  3! * 5! = 360, 2! * 3! * !5 = 720.

Comment: @jdehesa both my calculators and the calculation on paper get `3! * 5! = 720`.  Are you sure you didn't forget to take the factorial of 3 in `3! * 5!...`? I mean even the calculation above clearly shows that `6! = 5! * 3!`.

Comment: @Paul Haha, you're right! The calculator program I was using didn't work as I thought it should, sorry for the confusion.